# AZURE DATA FACTORY - Can I set a variable from within a CopyData task or by using the output?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have simple pipeline that has a Copy activity to populate a table. That task is based on a query and will only ever return 1 row.

The problem I am having is that I want to reuse the value from one of the columns (batch number) to set a variable so that at the end of the pipeline I can use a Stored Procedure to log that the batch was processed. I would rather avoid running the query a second time in a lookup task so can I make use of the data already being returned?

I have tried duplicating the column in the Copy activity and then mapping that to something like @BatchNo but that fails and have even tried to add a Set Variable task but can't figure out how to take a single column @{activity('Populate Aleprstw').output} does not error but not sure what that will actually do in this case.

Thanks and sorry if its a silly question.
Cheers
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always do it like this:

1. Generate a batch number (usually with a proc)
2. Use a lookup to grab it into a variable
3. Use the batch number in all activities (might be multiple copes, procs etc.)
4. Write the batch completion

From your description it seems you have the batch embedded in the data copy from the start which is not typical.

If you must do it this way, is there really an issue with running a lookup again?

Comment: Cheers; I have added an additional lookup in order to get it working; just felt wrong running the same query twice. This is my first ADF project and I am currently converting very old DTS packages to ADF with the guidance to keep things as close to the original as possible which is fun!

Answer (score 0):

Copy activity doesn't return data like that, so you won't be able to capture the results that way. With this design, running the query again in a Lookup is the best option.

Is the query in the Source running on the same Server as the Sink? If so, you could collapse the entire operation into a Stored Procedure that returns the data point you are trying to capture.

Comment: Thanks; they are on different servers so sp is not an option.